# C# EntityFramework Cast DBSet to Extended Entity which Inherits from Same DBSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

Firstly, I've searched for this solution quite a bit with no luck.

Here is my setup.

I have 2 Projects.

```
acme.data
acme.WebApi
```

acme.data is where all my Code First Classes live.

In the the following namespace
acme.data.models I have an Office Object (which properties like OfficeName, Address, etc)

I am using the namespace acme.WebApi.Models to put extensions on the Entity classes in acme.data.Models

So I have acme.WebApi.Models.Office (which has Methods like GetFormattedAddress, etc).

acme.WebApi.Models.Office is Inheriting from acme.data.Models.Office so that I can access the base acme.data.Models.Office and the extended acme.WebApi.Models.Office all from acme.WebApi.Models.Office

For Example,

```
acme.WebApi.Models.Office office = myOffice.GetFormattedAddress();
```

or

```
acme.WebApi.Models.Office office = myOffice.OfficeName();
```

This part works great. 
However,

When I first try to load Offices like this.

```
acme.WebApi.Models.Office office = db.Offices.FirstOrDefault();
```

I receive a compile time error saying it can't implicitly convert type acme.data.Models.Office to acme.WebApi.Models.Office

So I've added "as acme.WebApi.Models.Office" to convert acme.data.Models.Office first to acme.WebApi.Models.Office like this.

```
acme.WebApi.Models.Office office = db.Offices.FirstOrDefault() as acme.WebApi.Models.Office
```

This allows the 2 projects to build but when I run that line of code its setting office to Null.

So I tried casting the Office object a different way like this.

```
acme.WebApi.Models.Office office = (acme.WebApi.Models.Office)db.Offices.FirstOrDefault();
```

It lets me build both projects but at runtime I get this error. 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Office_D07C530EAB71F08D12EDDE4E5A80ECBE23A75424CDCDF1DC799A05A37B3032A7' to type 'acme.WebApi.Models.Office'.

Is there another way I should be casting or converting acme.data.Models.Office to acme.WebApi.Models.Office that won't involve me having to make a conversion method for each Entity class?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I think what your trying to do doesn't make sense. What you're getting back from EF is a proxy which can be used for lazy loading and change tracking etc. You should turn this off in your config I feel as it will make whats happening clearer.  Anyways the proxy will derive from the type that EF knows about - they are the code first classes you mention at the start. You're model also derives from these classes. But these two are not related past their parent.  So it appears you are trying to do a kind of "side-ways" cast.  This is not possible.

Comment: Maybe what your trying to do would be better done using "encapsulation" rather than "inheritance".  Investigate a simplified form of the "memento" pattern where you code first class lives "inside" the entity rather than as it's base class

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
Since acme.data.Models.Office and acme.WebApi.Models.Office are in 2 different namespaces in 2 different projects (therefore 2 different dll's) how will this encapsulation work?

Comment: Also we add  context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
Will that effect the way my objects are loaded? I thought I heard somewhere that If I have  ProxyCreationEnabled = false; I will have to add Include statements.

Comment: First, naming them the same is confusing. You will need a `DbSet<DerivedOffice>` to make this work. So where is your DbContext defined?

Comment: DBContext is defined in acme.data

Comment: @MonkeyMan when I Disable proxy creation I get this error message now.
Unable to cast object of type 'acme.data.Models.Office' to type 'acme.WebApi.Models.Office'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Where do I need to set    DBSet<DerivedOffice>

Comment: In your DbContext. Which, when you want to make this work, needs to move to the WebApi. But I think encapsulation is better.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This won't work because acme.data (where DBContext is) is used by other Applications in different solutions. Putting DBSet<DerrivedOffice>(Which would live in acme.WebApi.Models) would create a dependency for acme.WebApi.Models that wouldn't exists when acme.data is used in Other Solutions without acme.WebApi

Comment: Like I said, Encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not returning acme.Data.Models.Office?

Or otherwise you probably will want some other shared class, and you return the shared class.

```
acme.Data.Models.Office : acme.Shared.Model.Office
```

Otherwise you either

1. Convert Data to WebApi using converters/ConvertTo()
2. Have a WebApi Models which takes a Data Model and just wraps the properties.

Comment: acme.WebApi.Models.Office has some Extensions that I only want accessible by acme.WebApi

I could just make a wrapper, this just isn't very DRY. 

Thanks for your answer.